# magento 2 -how to show date time filter in sales order grid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In magento 2 sales order grid default date purchase filter is there, but i want to filter with date and time both. please help me how to do.

I tried like below but i didn't get any solution.

Thanks

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento_Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Date">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="timezone" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">MMM d</item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please follow given url to add new column in sales order grid : https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-column-in-sales-order-grid-in-magento-2-1.html

OR

you can use below code in `_prepareColumns()`.

```
$this->addColumn('shipped_date', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipped Date'),
      'index'     => 'entity_id',
      'type'      => 'datetime',
      'renderer'  => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_ShippedDate',
      'filter_condition_callback'
                                       => array($this, '_filterShippedDate'),

));
```

Comment: he doesn't want column, he needs filter, please read once again.

Comment: also, magento2 not m1.

Comment: thanks for this answer, so bad because it not what the question want, but its what i'm looking for, LOL, so thank you :)